# Pagination with AFIncrementalStore and AFRestClient

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking, afincrementalstore, afhttpclient

Can anyone show some sample on how to do the pagination with AFPaginator. I am using AFRestClient and I need to associate pagerId, offset and count parameters in my request for the entity.

It looks to me that by using AFPaginator associating these parameters should be straight forward. I have searched around for some examples and couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I could make some progress with pagination, but not completed.

If the fetch request has fetchLimit and fetchOffset not equal zero, it will create the parameters on request.

So, on my `AFRESTClient` subclass, before creating the request, on the method `-requestForFetchRequest:withContext:` I set the paginator as:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
self.paginator = [AFPageAndPerPagePaginator paginatorWithPageParameter:@"page" perPageParameter:@"per"];
[mutableParameters addEntriesFromDictionary:[self.paginator parametersForFetchRequest:fetchRequest]];
request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"feed" parameters:mutableParameters];
```

This will generate a request for something like `http://domain.com/feed?page=1&per=20`. The page is calculated based on `fetchOffset` and `FetchLimit` as

```
NSUInteger perPage = fetchRequest.fetchLimit == 0 ? kAFPaginationDefaultPerPage : fetchRequest.fetchLimit;
NSUInteger page = fetchRequest.fetchOffset == 0 ? kAFPaginationDefaultPage : (NSUInteger)floorf((float)fetchRequest.fetchOffset / (float)perPage) + 1;
```

So, I could make the fetch ask for a different page, but as I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` I couldn't make it ask for another page when I scroll a `UITableView`.  I tried to do something as:

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:[self.fetchedResultsController cacheName]];
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.fetchOffset = self.visibleChunk * self.chunkSize;
[_fetchedResultsController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performFetch:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO modes:@[ NSRunLoopCommonModes ]];
```

Here, `visibleChunk` should be used to bring another page, and `chunkSize` is the number of desired itens one API request.

This is not direct a response for your question, but I hope it can help you find the answer and post here :)

If I find something more, I update this.

Comment: I managed to make it work. But it does not work with NSFetchedResultsController. With NSFetchRequest, you just have to set `fetchOffset` with multiples of `fetchLimit`. So, if yo want to get the page 2 for 10 items per page, set `fetchOffset` equal 20, execute a new fetch with this changed NSFetchRequest object and you are done.